# Reset value of label created programatically inside a groupbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I create a `GroupBox` and `Label`s inside this `GroupBox`, so I want to know how can I access to all `GroupBox` of my `Form` and set `Label.Text` to `"0"`:

I try it as:

```
void clearLabels()
{    
    var labelList = this.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>();
    foreach (var item in labelList)
    {
        item.Text = "0";
    }
}
```

But it just set `0` to *title of groupbox* as:
[image]

is it possible to access `Label`s of a `GroupBox` to set them to `"0"` instead `Text` of `GroupBox`? Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems, you want *nested* loops:

```
void clearLabels()
{
    var groupBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>();

    // GroupBoxes
    foreach (var item in groupBoxes)
    {
        // Labels within GroupBox 
        foreach(var lbl in item.Controls.OfType<Label>()) 
        {
            lbl.Text = "0";
        }
    }
}
```